# Why is the Axios .then and .catch function incrementing my index?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, fetch, axios

I have a loop that is making up to five calls to an API endpoint to validate `ids`. My increment variable turns from `0` to `1` on the first iteration before finishing the loop.

I pinpointed that it happens whether the request is good or bad after console logging the variable right before the request and then inside each callback. As soon as the variable is called in the `.then` callback or the `.catch` callback, the index is incremented and I have no idea why. I have tested different variable names and still get the same result. Anyone have an idea on this?

I also used the `.fetch()` method with React and the same thing is happening in the `.then` function so I don't think this is specific to axios.

Here is my function:

```
isValidAIN(ains) {
  var control = this;
  var length = ains.length;

  if (ains.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      if (ains[i].length !== 10) {
        if (ains[i].length === 0) {
          this.state.errors["ain[" + i + "]"] = "";
          this.state.validAINS[i] = true;
        } else {
          this.state.errors["ain[" + i + "]"] = "This AIN Number Must Contain 10 Digits";
          this.state.validAINS[i] = false;
        }        
        this.setState(this.state);        

      } else {
        // v this logs 0
        console.log("i: ", i);

        axios
          .get("/myendpoint/?ain=" + ains[i])
          .then((res) => {
            //  v this logs 1
            console.log("in then: ", i);
            console.log("res: ", res);
            control.state.errors["ain[" + i + "]"] = "";
            control.state.validAINS[i] = true;
            control.setState(control.state);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            //  v this logs 1
            console.log("i in catch", i);

            if (err.response.status == 404) {
              control.state.errors["ain[" + i + "]"] = "AIN Is Invalid";
              console.log(control.state.errors["ain[" + i + "]"]);
              control.state.validAINS[i] = false;
              control.setState(control.state);
              return false;
            }
          });

        // fetch("/myendpoint/?ain=" + ains[i])
        // .then(res => res.json())
        // .then(
        //     (result) => {
        //         console.log("success: ", result);
        //         if(result == null) {
        //             control.state.errors["ain[" + i + "]"] = "AIN Is Invalid";
        //             control.state.validAINS[i] = false;
        //             control.setState(control.state);
        //             return false;
        //         }
        //         else {
        //             control.state.errors["ain[" + i + "]"] = "";
        //             control.state.validAINS[i] = true;
        //             control.setState(control.state);
        //         }
        //     },
        //     (error) => {
        //         console.log("error: ", error);
        //     }
        // )
        // .catch( 
        //     (err) => {
        //         console.log("Error from catch: ", err);
        //     }
        // )
      }
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do *not* directly modify state unless you are in the constructor.

Comment: The axios request is asynchronous, and the scope of variables declared with `var` is the enclosing function. When the axios request is complete, this variable will be the max of the loop, since the loop is complete. Change the `var` to `let` for `i` to use block scoping instead.

Comment: Ahhh @Tholle thank you so much that did the trick.

Comment: thanx for quick revision JakeG and Tholle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axios request is asynchronous, and the scope of variables declared with `var` is the enclosing function. When the axios request is complete, this variable will be the max of the loop, since the loop is synchronous and complete.

Change the `var` to `let` for `i` to use block scoping instead.

```
for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) { ... }
```

Comment: This fixed the issue but now creates an issue of the onBlur and submit not rechecking the function. Is the value of i being stored within the scope of this function? It seems the loop can no longer be recalled;

Comment: @JakeG That's frustrating. I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean. Consider creating another question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you can't find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Because axios calls are asynchronous.

You're performing a `for loop` that just loops through `ains.length`, this happens in a few milliseconds. You define `i` as a var that is incremented after every loop within the for loop.

So if you're in the `then` / `catch`, the variable `i` is already at its maximum (so 1 in your case).

`i` is a variable and not a constant. When using `i` you're referencing to that pointer in memory. If you want `i` to be unique in every loop you should define it as `let` instead of `var`. This will create a unique value of `i` for each invocation of the loop.

Comment: This fixed the issue but now creates an issue of the onBlur and submit not rechecking the function. Is the value of i being stored within the scope of this function? It seems the loop can no longer be recalled;